# SML and functional coding style

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm start to learn Standard ML with [Programming languages](https://www.coursera.org/course/proglang) course.

In the first homework, I try to write a function `is_older` that takes two dates and evaluates to `true` or `false`. It evaluates to `true` if the first argument is a date that comes before the second argument (If the two dates are the same, the result is `false`.).

So I write the following code:

```
fun is_older(first: int * int * int, second: int * int * int) =
  if(#1 first = #1 second andalso #2 first = #2 second andalso #3 first = #3 second) then false
  else if (#1 first < #1 second) then true
  else if (#1 first = #1 second andalso #2 first < #2 second) then true
  else if (#1 first = #1 second andalso #2 first = #2 second andalso #3 first < #3 second) then true
  else false
```

The code is works fine, but it looks ugly.

How can I rewrite this code in functional style?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Use pattern matching to decompose tuples.
- Use boolean operators (`andalso`, `orelse`, etc.) when `if/else` constructs return boolean.

A more readable version:

```
(* Compare two dates in the form of (year, month, day) *)
fun is_older((y1, m1, d1), (y2, m2, d2)) =
  y1 < y2 orelse (y1 = y2 andalso m1 < m2) 
  orelse (y1 = y2 andalso m1 = m2 andalso d1 < d2)
```

Answer (score 9):

In general when you have something on the form

```
if b then
  true
else
  false
```

you should exchange it with just `b`, as it is seen trivially to be the same. 
The solution provided by pad would probably also have been my solution, as it is nice and short.

However when you end up having those nasty/nested if-then-else's, and you don't return something simple (e.g., true/false or a number), then you should consider using a case. Your function is not a prime candidate to use, however I hope the below still shows the idea (that you easily can make structure of those nested if's)

```
fun is_older((y1, m1, d1), (y2, m2, d2)) =
    case (Int.compare(y1,y2), Int.compare(m1,m2), Int.compare(d1, d2)) of
      (LESS , _    , _   ) => true
    | (EQUAL, LESS , _   ) => true
    | (EQUAL, EQUAL, LESS) => true
    | _ => false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun is_older((yr1 : int , mo1 : int , dt1 : int), (yr2 : int , mo2 : int , dt2 : int )) =
  yr1 < yr2 orelse (yr1 = yr2 andalso mo1 < mo2) 
  orelse (yr1 = yr2 andalso mo1 = mo2 andalso dt1 < dt2)
```

Comment: Adding some comments will help others understand your answer propposal.