# SML Ml Programing Function is_older date with boolean conditon

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I am newbie in ML programming, I have a homework to write a function is_older that takes two dates and evaluates to true or false. It evaluates to true if the first argument is a date that comes before the second argument.
(If the two dates are the same,
the result is false.)

```
val is_older = fn : (int * int * int) * (int * int * int) -> bool // Binding Like
```

I tried this (using SML of New Jersy cmd prompt)

```
fun is_older((y1,m1,d1),(y2,m2,d2))= if (y1<y2) then true 
else if (y1=y2 andalso m1<m2) then true 
else if (y1=y2 andalso m1=m2 andalso d1<d2) then true;
```

Its gives error

```
Error syntax error: deleting SEMICOLON ID
```

Comment: You could realize your mistake by reading this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14374408/634025

Comment: @pad: thnks for link, i almost did same, so where i am wrong ?

Comment: You forgot the `else false` branch. Please see the answers there for improving your code as well.

Comment: @pad: Thank you sir i got it ,this my silly mistake make me in trouble for more then half n hrs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last `if` does not have an `else` - that's a syntax error in SML.

Comment: Cap F is my typo mistake i am using `fun`

Comment: @satindersingh You shouldn't retype your code when asking a question - you should copy and paste. If you introduce new errors when posting your code, that just makes it harder to answer your question.

Comment: thank you sir for spending you valuable time on my silly query

Answer (score 2):

```
fun is_older((y1 : int,m1 : int,d1 : int),(y2 : int, m2 : int, d2 : int))=
if y1 < y2 
then true 
else 
     if y1 = y2 andalso m1 < m2 
 then true 
 else 
      if y1 = y2 andalso m1 = m2 andalso d1 < d2
      then true 
      else false;
```